# Php update database if checkbox is not checked

Tags: php, mysql, checkbox

so I have a dynamically generated table

```
<tr>
    <td><?php echo $row['RequestID']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['FirstName'] . " " . $row['LastName']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DateRequested']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['DateNeeded']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['TotalPrice']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Company']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Account']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $row['Brand']?></td>
    <td><?php echo $quantity?></td>
    <td><input type="checkbox" name="bill[]" value=<?php echo '"' . $row['RequestID'] . '"'; if($row['BillBack'] == "1") {echo "checked='checked'"; } ?></td>
</tr>
```

and I want to update the database when a row is checked or unchecked.

```
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){//to run PHP script on submit
    if(!empty($_POST['bill'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['bill'] as $selected){
    echo "hello";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '1' WHERE RequestID = '$selected'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    }} elseif(empty($_POST['bill'])){
    // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
    foreach($_POST['bill'] as $selected){
    echo "hello";
    $sql2 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '0' WHERE RequestID = '$selected'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);
    }}

         }
```

Now. The if statement works like a charm. For every checked checkbox on a submit, that record gets updated. The issue comes with unchecking the checkboxes. As you can see, checked boxes are found by finding what is not empty. But, when I delete that exclamation point, it does not effectively do the opposite. It also doesn't work as it's own if statement, as a straight else statement, and checking for !isset. Is this because of how the inputs are deemed checked? is there a syntax error? I've done about 5 hours of error checking, googling, and I couldn't figure it out.
Thanks guys

Comment: Don't use `empty()` for checkboxes, use `isset()`.

Comment: @Fred-ii- like I said, !isset() still doesn't work. isset() works to set the checkboxes to checked. but !isset() doesn't set the checkboxes to unchecked.

Comment: Unchecked checkboxes do not get posted.  So, you need to find a different way to know which checkboxes didn't get checked and do your update accordingly.

Comment: ... and that way is to use a hidden input and based on an id column as an example.

Comment: @BizzyBob okay, but how would I do that? _GET['bill'] doesn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its very simple: just update ALL your entries to 0, an then set 1 on those that are checked.

```
//to run PHP script on submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){    
    // Setting everyone to 0
    $sql2 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '0'";
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    // Setting only those checked to 1
    if(!empty($_POST['bill'])){
        // Loop to store and display values of individual checked checkbox.
        foreach($_POST['bill'] as $selected){
            echo "hello";
            $sql3 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '1' WHERE RequestID = '$selected'";
            $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
        }
    }
}
```

EDIT:

Be aware that having queries inside a foreach may cause overload in your server, to avoid this, you can store the ids of entries that you want to update and use it in only one query outside the foreach:

```
//to run PHP script on submit
if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
    // Setting everyone to 0
    $sql2 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '0'"; // Maybe add a WHERE clause, like BizzyBob pointed out
    $result2 = $conn->query($sql2);

    // Setting only those checked to 1
    if(!empty($_POST['bill'])){

        // Initialize an array of selected ids
        $selected_ids = array(); 

        // Loop to store individual checked checkboxes on array        
        foreach($_POST['bill'] as $selected){
            $selected_ids[] = $selected;
        }

        // Get the ids separated by comma
        $in_clause = implode(", ", $selected_ids);

        // Do only one sql query
        $sql3 = "UPDATE Requests SET BillBack = '1' WHERE RequestID in (".$in_clause.")";
        $result3 = $conn->query($sql3);
    }
}
```

Comment: Be sure to add a `WHERE` clause to not affect rows that aren't relevant to the current transaction.

Comment: THANK YOU!  I made an edit, in case anyone wants to copy and paste, because the first usage of $sql vanilla is the beginning of the while loop, causing a fetch_assoc() error upon submit. Other than that, it's perfect, thank you so much